# PHP set default value to return record from ajax page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i am trying to set default value and get record on page load.

got options changes the record on changes the value in drop down

```
 <select id="maxDaysSinceAdded" name="shorting" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
 <option value="1">Most Recent</option>
 <option value="2">Lowest Price</option>
 <option value="3">Highst Price</option>
 </select>
```

java script to support getting data on changing drop down menu

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function showUser(str)
 {
 if (str=="")
 {
 document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
 return;
 } 
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else
 {
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
 {
 document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
 }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","productlistajax.php?q="+str,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
 </script>
```

showing the record inside div

```
 <div id="txtHint"><b></b></div>
```

please let me know how to set default value and get the record on load. its works fine on changing the drop down menu but would like to know how to show record of any option on load.

thanks for your help.
liz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to make one of the options selected by default:

```
 <option value="1">Most Recent</option>
 <option value="2"  selected='selected'>Lowest Price</option>
 <option value="3">Highst Price</option>
```

How to load the value (via Ajax) from the default one when page loads, create an onLoad function in your JS and put in it:

```
showUser(document.getElementById('maxDaysSinceAdded').value);
```

or the lazier way, put at the end of your HTML:

```
<script>showUser(document.getElementById('maxDaysSinceAdded').value);</script>
```